# How to extract text into dataframe or csv every line using python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a text file containing

```
[(XXX)].XX>[(XXX)].X.XXX
XXX.[(X)].[(XXX)]>>[(XXX)].XX
```

There are about 10k lines. [(XXX)], XX Theses can be 1 to 10 of them.

I want 2 data frame/CSV containing

Data frame 1

```
     1       2       3         
1 [(XXX)]   XX 
2 XXX      [(X)]  [(XXX)]
```

Data frame 2

```
     1        2    3   
1  [(XXX)]    X   XXX
2  [(XXX)]   XX
```

I am trying like this but failed

```
def get_sentences(filename):
    with open(filename) as file_contents:
        d1, d2 ,d3= '>', '>>','.' # just example delimiters
        results = []
        for line in file_contents:
            if d1 in line:
                results = []
            elif d2 in line:
                yield results
            else:
                results.append(line)
```

Appreciate any suggestion.

Actual dataset

```
[Na+].[CH3:2][C:3](=[O:5])[O-].[CH3:6][c:7]1[cH:12][cH:11][cH:10][cH:9][cH:8]1>>[c:7]1([CH3:6])[c:12]([C:3]([c:2]2[cH:11][cH:12][cH:7][cH:8][c:9]2[CH3:10])=[O:5])[cH:11][cH:10][cH:9][cH:8]1
[CH:1]1([C:4]([c:6]2[cH:11][cH:10][c:9]([C:12]([CH3:20])(C)[C:13](N(C)OC)=O)[cH:8][cH:7]2)=[O:5])[CH2:3][CH2:2]1.[BrH:21].[C:22](=[O:25])([O-])[OH:23].[Na+]>O>[Br:21][CH2:3][CH2:2][CH2:1][C:4]([c:6]1[cH:11][cH:10][c:9]([C:12]([CH3:20])([CH3:13])[C:22]([OH:23])=[O:25])[cH:8][cH:7]1)=[O:5]
```

Comment: Changing your question substantially after you received answers is bad because it invalidates tae answers you already received, and it's hard for a new visitor to understand how the answers relate to the now different question. You should probably roll back your latest edit and ac+ept one of the answers, then maybe post a new question with your *actual* requirements if you still can't figure it out. (Feel free to post an answer of your own and accept that, provided of course that it actually solves the question as originally stated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
import re
from io import StringIO

text = StringIO("""[(XXX)].XX>[(XXX)].X.XXX
XXX.[(X)].[(XXX)]>>[(XXX)].XX""")

df1, df2 = [], []

for l in text.readlines():
    x, y = re.split(r">+", l)
    df1.append(x.split("."))
    df2.append(y.split("."))

print(pd.DataFrame(df1))
print(pd.DataFrame(df2))
```

---

```
         0      1        2
0  [(XXX)]     XX     None
1      XXX  [(X)]  [(XXX)]

         0   1     2
0  [(XXX)]   X   XXX
1  [(XXX)]  XX  None
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake one sec.

Comment: p.splitlines()  ERROR >>> too many values to unpack (expected 2);;; readlines() ERROR 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Comment: f = open("Test(1).txt", "r")
text=f.read()   Got it now using readline()

Comment: try this, ```with open("Test(1).txt", "r") as f: for l in f.readlines()```

Answer (score 0):

At first, we are opening a file and using the `readlines()` function to grab all lines. Then we are iterating over the `data` variable and splitting the line by the `.`. Then we are creating a new dictionary element - the first element of `splitter` is the key, the others are the value. At the end, using the `pandas` `DataFrame()` function we are creating a `DataFrame` using created `dictionary`

```
import pandas as pd
with open('file_name.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
buffer = {}
for i in data:
    splitter = i.split('.')
    buffer[splitter[0]] = splitter[1:]
df = pd.DataFrame(buffer)
```

Comment: Can you please tell  that if the text file contain  only two line or more?

Comment: There are about 10k lines. [(XXX)], XX Theses can be 1 to 10 of them.

Comment: Oh, I tried your also but am still facing a problem I have added the actual dataset at the bottom of the post (First two lines). Can you please help.